# Web site DNS configuration Without using hosting nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

i am publishing my website(www.muratturan.com) by using godaddy's "Total DNS Control". My configuration like this:

1-) I configured my domain to total dns control by setting nameservers to total dns control's.
2-) In total dns control panel i set A host to directly my VPS's ip address.
3-) Also i configured mx records to google apps.

Everythings looks good but i am thinking that is this technuqie has any negative effects ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds perfectly normal to me.

One common mistake in this sort of a situation would be failing to ensure that "muratturan.com" resolves to the same IP address as "www.muratturan.com"; at the most basic level, this is a A record for "@" (in addition to the one for "www").  It looks like you have already done this.

Answer (score 2):

According to intodns; you dont have any problem with your dns configuration.

http://www.intodns.com/muratturan.com

one warning about your MX ip address's have no reverse dns (PTR) record. you need to talk service provider to get a PTR record for your mail exchangers. Many public e-mail provider don't like to get SMTP connection for an ip address without PTR. eg. gmail. or most of time marks mail as spam.

& also Godaddy's dns service is reliable and stable enough. 
i had been using it more than 3 years with no problem.